# Need to switch between 3 divs but unable to work out the js

Tags: javascript

I'm using switch visible to switch between 3 visible elements on button press, but am only able to get 2. Thanks for the help :)

```js
function switchVisible() {
  if (document.getElementById('text1')) {
      if (document.getElementById('text1').style.display == 'none') {
          document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('text2').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('text3').style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('text2').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('text3').style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
}
```

```css
#text1, #text2, #text3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text1">text 1</div>
<div id="text2">text 2</div>
<div id="text3">text 3</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below approach to achieve this. Use a switch statment and a count vairable to keep track of 3 divs.

**Full working code snippet:**

```js
let count = 1;

function switchVisible() {

  switch (count) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('text2').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('text3').style.display = 'none';
      count++;
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('text2').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('text3').style.display = 'none';
      count++
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('text2').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('text3').style.display = 'block';
      count = 1
      break;
    default:
      count = 1
  }
}
```

```css
#text1,
#text2,
#text3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text1">text 1</div>
<div id="text2">text 2</div>
<div id="text3">text 3</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();" />
```

Hope that's how you wanted it work.

Comment: All answers posted likely work, but I really like this one since it's easiest to read for me at least. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

to do this one proposal can be :

- have an array of all div id to switch
- have a rolling index that say which div should be displayed

```js
var divIds = [
  'text1',
  'text2',
  'text3'
];

var visibleIndex = 0;

function switchVisible() {
  divIds.forEach(id => {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  });
  document.getElementById(divIds[visibleIndex]).style.display = 'block';
  visibleIndex++;
  if (visibleIndex === divIds.length) {
    visibleIndex = 0;
  }
}

switchVisible();
```

```css
#text1, #text2, #text3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text1">text 1</div>
<div id="text2">text 2</div>
<div id="text3">text 3</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A class would be better to mark all elements of a collection.

*Sidenote: In my experience classes are almost always better, as they can be applied to a single or to multiple elements.
IDs are imo. more for special cases. They address a single element which must be unique throughout the entire page.*

Now back to topic:

About the toggling, you can either keep track of the visible element in a variable:

```js
let visible = 0;

function switchVisible() {
  const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tab"));
  
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    element.style.display = index === visible ? "block" : "none";
  });

  // increment visible
  visible = (visible + 1) % elements.length;
}
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">text 1</div>
<div class="tab">text 2</div>
<div class="tab">text 3</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();" />
```

or you find out which one is visible in the function itself.

```js
function switchVisible() {
  const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tab"));
  
  // checking which one is the first that has some dimension
  let visible = elements.findIndex(element => element.offsetWidth || element.offsetHeight);
  
  // increment visible
  visible = (visible + 1) % elements.length;
  
  // make this "next one" visible
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    element.style.display = index === visible ? "block" : "none";
  });
}
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">text 1</div>
<div class="tab">text 2</div>
<div class="tab">text 3</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible()" />
```